# inline function issue in c

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, inline

I have a large C project build in Visual Studio 2010. I have declared one of the function as inline, which is called more often. I have declared function `pdebug` as:

```
void inline pdebug(int debug_mask,int level,char *format,...);
```

in `debug.h` and its definition in `debug.c` in the same directory.

The files which uses this function `pdebug`, i have done `#include<debug.h>`.

Compilation fails with these errors:

```
debug.h(13): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'pdebug'
debug.h(13): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
debug.h(13): error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you compile the code as "C" and Visual Studio supports `inline` only in C++.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx

> The inline keyword is available only in C++. The __inline and __forceinline keywords are available in both C and C++. For compatibility with previous versions, _inline is a synonym for __inline.

And of course, see the other answers for th correct order.

But ...

You seem to have this function with variadic parameters ... inlinining a function like this is not recommended (by me, but I'm not an expert in this), because depending on compiler settings your code will grow to tremendous size (if the compiler really decides that it will inline this). Inline is perfect for small functions, which are not made up of several statements. Inlining big functions will possibly result in big code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `inline void pdebug` not `void inline pdebug`.

Comment: now i got the below errors.

"""""
debug.h(13): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'

debug.h(13): error C2085: 'pdebug' : not in formal parameter list

"""""""""

Comment: You probably forgot an `;` before including `debug.h`, most likely in the .h file included just before `debug.h`.

Comment: if i comment this declaration in debug.h then compilation is successful